# Spark , OOM on left join ( inner is fine) , How do I disable boardcast for specific dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, join, left-join

I have two dataframe with exactly same join keys

spark config:

```
spark_config = {
    'spark.driver.memory': '1g',
    'spark.driver.maxResultSize': '1g',
    'spark.executor.memory': '1g',
    'spark.executor.memoryOverhead': '1g',
    'spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max': 1024,
    'spark.executor.instances': 2,
    'spark.executor.cores': 1,
    ...
}
```

#### Inner join is fine

```
df1 = spark.read.parquet('/data/pipeline-workspace/91_active/3d2e21c0-3d0f-11ec-a384-b9dfba307662/segment')
df2 = spark.read.parquet('/data/pipeline-workspace/91_active/b0fe56e6-01d8-4e18-a8a8-d53e4e363fe8/daily_merged2')
df3 = df1.drop('__uuid__', '__timestamp__').join(df2, on="__label_id__", how='inner')
df3.write.parquet('/data/test', mode='overwrite')
```

count :

```
>>> df1.count()
102301
>>> df2.count()
102301
>>> df3.count()
102301
```

##### But left join got OOM

```
df3 = df1.drop('__uuid__', '__timestamp__').join(df2, on="__label_id__", how='left')
df3.write.parquet('/data/test', mode='overwrite')
```

logs:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o374.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:696)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:586)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Not enough memory to build and broadcast the table to all worker nodes. As a workaround, you can either disable broadcast by setting spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to -1 or increase the spark driver memory by setting spark.driver.memory to a higher value
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:75)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Set `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1`  does solve the OOM, but it is not the correct behavior. Because we need autoBroadcast little table, shouldn't disable it .

I tried `df2.collect()` got OOM too,
so the problem becomes:

1. why spark think the size of `df2` is lower than 10M ?
2. Could I mark the `df2` with some tag `no auto broadcast` so that don't need to set `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=-1`

Comment: Adding a hint doesn't help? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#hint-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: @mazaneicha need hint that df don't broadcast

Comment: `"shuffle_hash"` or `"merge"` ? As always, source is the best place to look -- https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/hints.scala#L138

Comment: @mazaneicha Looks like spark 2.4 doesn't contain those hints  : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-performance-tuning.html#broadcast-hint-for-sql-queries ,  https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/hints.scala#L138

Comment: No it doesn't...